# Inertia of a body cancells some amount of force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we have a block on a frictionless surface and we apply force F on the block to accelerate it, some amount of applied force will be cancelled by the inertia of the block am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite; inertia is not a force. The whole force will be used to accelerate the block ; the corresponding amount of acceleration is defined by the mass of the block as $\vec F = m \vec a$.